# Is there any quick solution to use "this" scope for the existing jquery code?

Tags: jquery

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('.selecter1')......
    $('.selecter2')......
    $('.selecter3')......
});
```

I have a jquery code with n number of lines like above, I would like to maintain the code using $(this) scope. Is there any quick/one line solution? Please note that it's very difficult to me to go to the each line and make it like below.

```
$(this).closest('.parent-element').find('.selector1').....
```

Please help.

More code sample

```
$('.digital_schedule .custom_date').animate({ height: "275px", opacity: "1" }, 300).show();
$('.digital_schedule .custom_date .Zebra_DatePicker').show();
$('.digital_schedule .custom_date').data('Zebra_DatePicker').show();
var d = $('#custom_delivery_date option[value=other]').data('date');
var display_date = moment(d).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
var deliverySelect = moment(setTime()).format("lll");
$('.first-cart .complete-cart').find('.rs-delivery').removeClass('hide').html('<span class="icon-stop-watch icon"></span> ' + deliverySelect);
$('.label_li').show();
$('.label_li .scheduled_date').html(display_date);
$('.visible_select_wr').html($('.full_option_select').html());
$('.visible_select_wr select').addClass('schedule_time custom_select').styledSelect();
$('.schedule2_li, .schedule3_li').animate({opacity: "1"}, 300).show();
```

Comment: Can you share more code? and possible HTML, Specially `$('.selecter1')......` and `$('.selecter2')......`

Comment: There's no quick/one line solution that will solve all possibilities/variations of code that you have now or in the future.  Code is a bit more specific than that.  You may be able to reuse some code and use `this` as you've suggested, but there's not much that can be done with minimal amount of code provided as this code has no relation to the rest of the (minimal) code provided.  Perhaps you could provide more code / explain what you're trying to do / explain why it's difficult to write the code you need.

Comment: It will look like my above sample, The second sample my straight solution, But I hope there is some more elegant solution.

Comment: We need to understand what `.....` perform, Do they perform same or otherwise? What all common thing which we can use. In short term, How we can refactor the code so that  you don't need to change so many lines

Comment: if you bind `change` event to `.parent-element`, the scope will be this parent element. The `select` element will be the `event.target`. Now it is not really clear to me how your new posted code is relevant to your question. But if you want to avoid using `$(this).closest('.parent-element').find('...')` and use instead `$(this).find('...')`, my suggestion would help.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand, it's a piece of code from the original. I do not fully get your solution, but I am sure that I am looking for a solution like attach/restrict the scope with parent element, not siblings.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it automatically treat `$(".selector")` as if you'd written `$(this).find(".selector")` so you don't have to repeat `$(this).find()` every time? As far as I know, there's nothing that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You may use it .

```
var obj = $(this).closest('.parent-element');
obj.find('div[class^="selector"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Hope , it will help you .

Comment: Sorry unable to use your suggestion, because none of the selectors is common.